# Invalid character at the end of Folder name

Tags: linux, ftp

I am using RHEL 7. Previously I was working with 5.5.
We have a big FTP server configured by proftp with mysql.

The problem is, I need to take the folder names and create same folders to the new server.

I am doing like below:

```
ls > /abc/folders.txt
```

then I move the txt file to the new server and use the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

N=0
cat folders.txt | while read LINE ; do
        N=$((N+1))
        mkdir /ftp/FTP/$LINE
done
```

It is creating the folders, but all the folders are having a "?" at the end like below:

```
zhl?
heing?                          zieha?
hvejen?                        ziga?
hellgrafisk?                  zinernagel?
```

It worked fine on RHEL 5.5. How to solve it?

Comment: You probably have MS-DOS (CR+LF) line endings in folders.txt, so you're getting a stray CR character when you read each line. Fix your line endings and you should be OK.

Comment: Did you check the contents of `folders.txt`? Does it look fine? Did you try to `echo $LINE` in order to check if the variable itself contains the invalid character?

Comment: Paul - thanks for you advice - yes there stray character - its not possible to manually remove them 1556 entries. :(

Seth - I checked the files several times - only stray characters - nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some non-printable characters on end of lines (eg. `CRLF` from Windows), run:

```
cat -A folders.txt
```

on remote machine, it'll show you all characters in your script. Then, you can convert to unix-like format running

```
dos2unix folders.txt
```